# WordPress default theme CSS version problem and not loading

Tags: css

WordPress default theme CSS version problem and not loading.

After change the css code not apply the old css only load.

we manually the style version the new code load.

```
style.css?ver=5.1 to style.css?ver=5.2
```

How to change wordpress default theme style.css version in WordPress v 5.1

Comment: I don’t understand the question. Why do you need to change just the _version_ of the default theme’s CSS?

Comment: we changed in css code not apply.. 'style.css?ver=1' then we change manually 'style.css?ver=2' it loading new code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass **time()** function in version parameter. so you dont have to change version to update a css code.

```
function add_dynamic_version_css_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'dynamic-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom-style.css','style-css', time() );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_dynamic_version_css_scripts' );
```

let me know if this works for you.

Comment: this is Custom-style.css i asking default css file

Comment: yeah, this is just an example. you can add time() in your default css where you enqueue file.

Comment: ok we try this time()

Comment: yes. try this.  it will generate unique version of file so you dont have to update version every time when you change code in css file. you can also use in js file if you face issue in js version also. let me know if this solve your problem.